# Master Data Services - Domain based attributes

Tags: master-data-services, mds

We are using Master Data Services as an MDM solution for our SQL Server BI environment. I have an entity containing a first name and last name and then I have created a business rule that concatenates these two fields to form a full name which is then stored in the "name" system field of the entity.

I use this as a domain based entity in another entity. Then the user can then see the full name before linking it as a attribute in the second entity.

I want to be able to restrict the users from capturing data in the first entity against the name attribute because the business rule deals with the logic to populate this attribute. I have read that there are two ways to do this:

1. Set the display width to zero of the attribute. This does not seem to work, the explorer version still shows a narrow version of the field in the rows and the user can still edit the field in the detail pane.
2. Use the security to make the attribute read only. I have tried different combinations of this but it seems that you cannot use this functionality for a name field (system field).

This seems like pretty basic functionality that I require and it seems that there is no clear cut way to do this in MDS.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We do exactly the same thing.

I tested it, and whether you create a new member, or edit an existing member, the business rule just overwrites the manual input value in the name attribute.

Is there a specific 'business' reason why you need to restrict data input in the name field? If it is for Ux reasons, you can change the display name of the name attribute to something like 'Don't populate' or alternatively make it a '.', then the users won't know what to input.